# Checking exercise on uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

I have solved the following exercise and I would like someone to check and tell me if my solution is right. Thank you.

Let $f_n(x)=\frac{nx}{1+nx^2}$
(a) Find the pointwise limit of $(f_n)$ for all $x\in (0,\infty)$
(b) Is the convergence uniform on $(0,\infty)$?
(c) Is the convergence uniform on $(0,1)$?
(d) Is the convergence uniform on $(1,\infty)$?

My solution (NOTE: corrected parts (b) and (c) thanks to the answers below):
(a) $f_n(x)=\frac{nx}{1+nx^2}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{nx}+x}\xrightarrow[]{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{x} $

In what follows we use the fact that if $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $(0,\infty)$ or $(0,1)$ then $|f_n(a_n)-f(a_n)|\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$ (where $(a_n)$ is a sequence of points belonging to these spaces.)

(b) Consider the sequence $(a_n)=\frac{1}{n}$; then $|f_n(a_n)-\frac{1}{a_n}|=|\frac{n}{n+1}-n|=|-\frac{n^2}{n+1}|=\frac{n^2}{n+1}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\infty$ thus the convergence is not uniform here.

(c) The convergence is not uniform by the same reasoning as in part (b)

(d) $|f_n(x)-\frac{1}{x}|=\frac{1}{x(1+nx^2)}\leq\frac{1}{1\cdot (1+1\cdot n)}=\frac{1}{1+n}\leq\frac{1}{n}$. Thus, given $\varepsilon > 0$ we can choose $N >\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$ (independent of $x$) and it follows that $n\geq N$ implies $|f_n(x)-\frac{1}{x}|\leq\varepsilon$ for all $x\in (0,1)$ so here we have uniform convergence.

Comment: For (b) and (c) I prefer to look for $x_n$ such that $f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)\not\to0$, I think $x_n=1/n$ willl work.

Comment: The standard route to prove of disprove uniform convergence is to look at the variations : this is how extremas can be found. Here a simpler method is to notice that you have a term of the form $1+nx^2$ so choosing $x^2n=1$ (to balance both terms) tells you what happens :  $| f_n(n^{-1/2}) -n^{1/2} |= n^{1/2}/2 \to \infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is almost correct. Here is a problem in parts (b) and (c), which is this: you used the inequality$$\left|f_n(x)-\frac1x\right|\leqslant\frac1{nx^3}$$and then you stated that, since $\frac1{nx^3}$ is not arbitrarily small uniformly, then the convergence is not uniform. That is not correct. For instance, $\frac xn$ converges uniformly to $0$ on $[0,1]$. But you also have $|f_n(x)-0|\leqslant1$ on $[0,1]$, and the constant function $1$ is not arbitrarily small uniformly.

In order to do (b) and (c), just use the fact that$$(\forall n\in\Bbb N):f_n\left(\frac1n\right)=\frac n{n+1}\to_{n\to\infty}1.$$

Comment: Carlos Santos: so, if I understand correctly, you have used the fact that $|f_n (x)-f(x)|\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\Rightarrow |f_n(x_n)-f(x)|\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$ and by finding a sequence $(x_n)$ such that the latter limit doesn't converge to 0 you argue that the former does not converge to 0 too. Is this correct?

Comment: No. What I did was this: if $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges uniformly to $\frac1x$ on $(0,\infty)$, then, for each sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ of elements of $(0,\infty)$, you have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|f_n(a_n)-\frac1{a_n}\right|=0$. But, by taking $a_n=\frac1n$, I know that that is not true. Therefore, the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: corrected and answer accepted; thank you.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: I have tried to prove the result that you showed me here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3955418/showing-there-isnt-uniform-convergence-a-useful-lemma if you are interested. Thank you for your time.